# Call by reference of bool types

Tags: c++, boolean, pass-by-reference

How can I change this piece of code to a working one?!

```
#include <iostream>

void foo( bool &b )  // ERROR in passing argument 1 of ‘void foo(bool&)’
{
   std::cout << b << '\n';
}

int main()
{
  foo( false );   // ERROR invalid initialization of non-const reference of type ‘bool&’ from a temporary of type ‘bool’
  return 0;
}
```

Please note that I **want** to use call by reference method using `&b`.

Comment: use const bool& instead of bool&

Comment: In your example, why would you need it by reference?

Comment: @omid Or simply `bool`.

Comment: @keyser: This is a snippet of a larger code!

Comment: Also note this has nothing to do with the type being `bool`.

Comment: @mahmood What matters is if you have a variable or not

Comment: @keyser: Yes that is also possible based on michaelBurns's answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foo( false );
```

this calls foo with a temporary object of type bool.

You cannot bind a temporary to non-const reference thus the error. It is possible in case of const reference

```
void foo( const bool &b );
//...
foo( false ); // OK
```

In your case it seems that you don't want to change an object being passed to the function but just to print it. Then there is no need to pass a reference, you can just pass object by value.

```
void foo( bool b ) { std::cout << b;}
//...
foo( false ); // OK
```

Comment: `Then there is no need to pass a reference, you can just pass object by value.` Only true with small objects. What if the object passed was a large datastructure? still better to have &.

Answer (score 2):

call by reference requires an address, you're passing a constant. why no

```
bool aValue;
aValue = false;
foo(aValue);
```

Comment: That is also possible.

Comment: It doesn't really require "an address".

Comment: forgive me if im wrong, but is it not the memory location on the stack/heap that is passed to the function, as opposed to the value that resides at the memory location?

Comment: That would be an implementation detail. Semantically, a reference is just an alias for an object. In this case, what is needed is an *lvalue*.